# Method invocation order

Tags: java, methods

Suppose I have a method which contains invocation of 3 another methods. How can I set invocation order of internal methods depends on parameter? For instance,

```
public void method(int i){
    if(i == 0){
        anotherMethod1();
        anotherMethod2();        
        anotherMethod3();
    } else if(i == 1){
        anotherMethod2();
        anotherMethod1();        
        anotherMethod3();
    } else if(i == 2){
        anotherMethod3();
        anotherMethod2();        
        anotherMethod1();
    }

    //ETC
```

Is there a way to do it without multiple `if-else` clauses?

Comment: Looks like a bad design pattern.

Comment: Why the order of your method calls modifies your program behavior? This rings a "bad design" bell for me

Comment: @hsz What you're talking about?

Comment: @Narmer Because of the program itself. To rewrite it entirely is very bad idea.

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @DavidWallace Java 5.

Comment: Why on earth would you run Java 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you're using Java 5 (!), so Java 8's lambdas are out.

You pretty much have three choices:

1. `if/else if/else if` as in your example.
2. `switch`, which is similar.
3. A `Map` (or array) of arrays of interface references, where you implement the interface by calling each of your methods. The outer `Map`/array is what you index into with the argument, and the arrays it contains are the methods to call in the order in which you want to call them. E.g., a dispatch map that gives you a list of the methods in the right order, wrapped in an interface so you store references to them.
4. #3, but using reflection instead, so the inner arrays are arrays of `Method`.

#3 and #4 are almost certainly **way** over the top.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like #3.  I had kind of assumed that there must be more than just the three methods to call, and more than just three possible values for the parameter.  Otherwise, there's no reason for OP to dislike using `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to to do it for 3 methods, you can do something like this:

```
int[][] orderOfExecution = {{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{2,1,3},{2,3,1},{3,2,1},{3,1,2}};

void executeMethod(int x){
   switch(x){
       case 1: anotherMethod1(); break;
       case 2: anotherMethod2(); break;
       case 3: anotherMethod3(); break;
   }
}
```

and your `method()` method should look something like this:

```
void method(int x){
    for(int i : orderOfExecution[x])
        executeMethod(i);
}
```

Now this won't be as good if you want to do it for many more methods but nevertheless if you want to do it you can create a method that returns all possible permutations of an array of size `n` where `n` is the number of methods you wanna execute this way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now that's a much nicer way to approach my #3/#4 scenario, particularly for Java 5. +1!